# How do you create an action in MVC with oData

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, odata

I have tried to follow the example code at

https://aspnet.codeplex.com/sourcecontrol/latest#Samples/WebApi/ODataActionsSample/ODataActionsSample/NonBindableActionRoutingConvention.cs

as well as I can.

WebApiConfig:

```
        config.Routes.MapODataRoute(
                "AppAccountOData",
                "odata",
                GetModel()
            );
```

...

API routes
...

```
        public static IEdmModel GetModel()
    {
        var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
        builder.EntitySet<User>("Users");
        builder.EntitySet<EventLog>("EventLogs");
        builder.EntitySet<Server>("Servers");
        builder.EntitySet<Database>("Databass");
        builder.EntitySet<Command>("Commands");
        builder.EntitySet<Connection>("Conenctions");
        builder.EntitySet<Query>("Queries");
        builder.EntitySet<DirectoryGroup>("DirectoryGroups");
        builder.EntitySet<ServiceAccount>("ServiceAccounts");
        builder.EntitySet<EmailLog>("EmailLogs");
        builder.EntitySet<EmailTemplate>("EmailTemplates");
        builder.EntitySet<EventLog>("EventLogs");
        builder.EntitySet<EventLogLevel>("EventLogLevels");
        builder.EntitySet<EventLogSource>("EventLogSources");
        builder.EntitySet<ApplicationServer>("ApplicationServers");
        builder.EntitySet<ApplicationOnboardings_Old>("ApplicationOnboardings_Olds");
        builder.EntitySet<ApplicationContact>("ApplicationContacts");
        builder.EntitySet<ApplicationCategory>("ApplicationCategories");
        builder.EntitySet<ApplicationOnboardingStatusType>("ApplicationOnboardingStatusTypes");
        builder.EntitySet<ApplicationOnboarding>("ApplicationOnboardings");
        builder.EntitySet<Application>("Applications");
        builder.EntitySet<AppAccount>("AppAccounts");
        builder.EntitySet<vAppAccountUser>("vAppAccountUsers");
        builder.EntitySet<vUnmatchedAppAccount>("vUnmatchedAppAccounts");
        builder.EntitySet<vTerminatedUser>("vTerminatedUsers");
        builder.EntitySet<SvcAccount>("SvcAccounts");
        builder.EntitySet<AppAccountClass>("AppAccountClasses");

        var serviceAccounts = builder.Entity<AppAccount>().Collection.Action("Service");
        serviceAccounts.ReturnsCollectionFromEntitySet<AppAccount>("AppAccounts");

        return builder.GetEdmModel();

    }
```

The function in the controller is simple:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ICollection<AppAccount> Service(ODataQueryOptions opts)
    {
        var results = opts.ApplyTo(db.AppAccounts.Where(aa => aa.AppAccountClass.Name == "Service")) as IQueryable<AppAccount>;
        if (results != null) return results.ToList();
        throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
```

When I call this, I receive an error:

Not implemented. This service doesn't support OData requests in the form '~/entityset/action'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OData action invocations are HTTP POST's. So, your controller code should look like this instead,

```
[HttpPost]
public ICollection<AppAccount> Service(ODataQueryOptions opts)
{
    var results = opts.ApplyTo(db.AppAccounts.Where(aa => aa.AppAccountClass.Name == "Service")) as IQueryable<AppAccount>;
    if (results != null) return results.ToList();
    throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
}
```

Looking at your code, I think you want OData function support, which hasn't been implemented in web API yet.

Comment: Yeah. This now throws an error as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17261450/additional-getxyz-methods-in-entitysetcontroller